# Why is the plugin not working on all elements except the first one

Tags: jquery

I created [this](https://github.com/raynesax/image-resize-jquery-plugin) image resizing plugin last night.The problem is if there is only one 'div.content',I can do the following to make it work:

```
window.onload=function(){
     $('div.content').image_resizer();
}
```

But when I add few more such 'div.content' and do:

```
window.onload=function(){
         $.each($('div.content'),function(k,v){
           $(this).image_resizer();
         });
}
```

The plugin works on the very first div.content and fail for rest of 'div.content'.Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

[EDIT]
here is the markup:

```
<div class="content">
        <img src="./images/img5.jpg" id='p1'/>
</div>
```

[EDIT 2]
One more thing,when I feed 
`$.each($('div.content'),function(k,v){$(this).image_resizer()});` manually into chrome's console.All the images resize themselves to fit into their respective divs.

[Plugin Code]

```
(function($){
    $.fn.image_resizer = function(options){
        $.fn.image_resizer.defaults = { MAX_HEIGHT : 280,MAX_WIDTH : 330,BORDER_WIDTH : 10 }
        var opts = $.extend({},$.fn.image_resizer.defaults,options);
        return this.each(function(){
            //plugin code starts here

            // getting array of all the images inside 'di$(this)' on which this plugin is applied
            var arr =  $(this).find('img');

            //iterating o$(this)er the array 'arr'
            $.each(arr,function(k){
                //console.log(k,$(this))
                // now resizing the image

                img_hit=$(this).height();
                img_wit=$(this).width();
                //console.log(img_hit,img_wit);
                //calculating image height to width ratio
                var ratio = img_hit/img_wit;
                if(img_wit>img_hit){
                    //console.log("wit module");
                    if(img_wit>opts.MAX_WIDTH){
                        //console.log("Image needs resizing");
                        new_wit=opts.MAX_WIDTH-(opts.BORDER_WIDTH*2);
                        $(this).width(new_wit);
                        //console.log(new_wit);
                        var new_hit = ratio*new_wit;
                        $(this).height(new_hit)
                        var space = opts.MAX_HEIGHT-(new_hit+(opts.BORDER_WIDTH*2));
                        //console.log(space);
                        $(this).css('margin-top',space/2);
                        $(this).css('margin-bottom',space/2);
                    }else{
                        //console.log("Image doesn't need resizing")
                        var space = opts.MAX_HEIGHT-(img_hit+(opts.BORDER_WIDTH*2));
                        //console.log(space);
                        $(this).css('margin-top',space/2);
                        $(this).css('margin-bottom',space/2);
                    }
                }else{
                    //console.log("hit module");
                    if(img_hit>opts.MAX_HEIGHT){
                        //console.log("Image needs resizing");
                        new_hit = opts.MAX_HEIGHT-(opts.BORDER_WIDTH*2);
                        $(this).height(new_hit);
                        var new_wit = new_hit/ratio;
                        $(this).width(new_wit);
                    }else{
                        //console.log("Image doesn't need resizing");
                        var space = opts.MAX_HEIGHT-(img_hit+(opts.BORDER_WIDTH*2));
                        //console.log(space);
                        $(this).css('margin-top',space/2);
                        $(this).css('margin-bottom',space/2);
                    }
                }

            });

            //plugin code ends here
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I cannot tell you why it does not work, but if you want to iterate over the elements, you should use `$(selector).each(function() {...});` (also in your plugin). If you write your plugin correctly (which it looks like you did), then `$('div.content').image_resizer()` should also work for multiple elements. Please be more precise what you mean with it "fails for rest". What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Also post your markup for us to have more details.

Comment: Just two side notes: you can use `.each` on a set, and you are resetting the defaults on each call.

Comment: Please explain what you meant by "resetting the defaults".Are you talking about the plugin code or the code shown here?

Comment: Please post the code from your plugin rather than a Github link.  SO questions should be self-contained and not rely solely on external links.  Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't your plugin already do the iteration for you? Use **$('div.content').image_resizer();** whether you have one or many **div.content** elements.

Comment: Hey,I solved this problem.I initially had 'display: none' for all the divs so the plugin was not working.Now I've changed that to 'display: block',Now everything is working fine.

Comment: You set `$.fn.image_reiszer.defaults` when you call `.image_resizer()`. You probably want to set the defaults when the page loads and not reset them on each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine here [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Q9Ur/)

This suggests a markup error somewhere.

As pointed out by others, there is no need to iterate.  You can simply just use: $('div.content').image_resizer();